# Using Virtual environments in Sublime. Cant import modules

Tags: python, virtualenv, sublimetext3, python-venv

So I started programming 1 -2 months ago with python and I am using Sublime Text3. I tried to read about it but I don't seem to understand how to link my virtualenv to my python project. 
When I create my virtualenv in the terminal (I am on macOS) and I open a new project in sublime I can't import my installed modules. How do I add the env to my python project?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at PyCharm (instead of sublime). It's a great IDE for python.
I'm not sure how sublime works, but on PyCharm you can set an interpreter for a project and give it the path to your virtual env. Maybe there's something similar in sublime as well..?
My venv paths are usually something like `wherever_you_store_your_project/project_name/venv/bin/python`

EDIT
The `venv` in the path is how I name my virtual environments

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out:). But does maybe someone else know how to make it work with sublime?